# Query for all records in `belongsToMany` if specific record is one of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, relational-database, sequelize.js

I have a `User` model, a `Message` model and a `Group` model. `Message belongsTo Group`, `Group belongsToMany User(group_members, { as: 'members' })`
I want to query all messages where a particular user is a member of its group. I achieved this with an `include` on `Message` like so:

```
include: [ {
  model: Group,
  include: {
    association: 'members',
    where: {
      id: userId
    }
  },
  required: true
} ]
```

However this returns `Message.Group.members` as an array of *only* the user I checked for. This is of course expected but what would I do if I want all the members (where `userId` is one of them)?

EDIT - [This](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8754) seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your where condition should be outside of the include. With the required creating an inner join, you can filter the results like that :

```
models.Message.findAll({
    attributes: [ 'idcustomer', 'firstname', 'lastname' ],
    include: [ {
        model: Group,
        include: {
          association: 'members'  
        }
    } ]
    where: {
        'group.members.id': userId
    }
});
```

This should work.

Comment: I will have to test it later, though it looks promising. Is `required: true` required (pun intended) in both `include`s?

Comment: required make sure you don't get empty members or groups, but no with the where condition this is actually not required ! Put it by habit. Let me know how it goes !

Comment: It worked perfectly, but there was a typo in your example and it could be simpler. I will suggest an edit.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but my code wasn't working properly and this query was never really executed. Now that I found the problem, the query fails with `column Message.group.members.id does not exist`..

Comment: Try to log the query, I think it comes from the joined names, as sequelize generate names for every joined query babsed on the association. For example, for group it might be "groups" or "Group" or "Groups". You can log the query by changing sequelize config (if I remember correctly, it should be something like log: console.log)

Comment: I can confirm Sequelize sets it as `group.members` from the query.

Comment: then maybe replace where: { 'group.members.id': userId } by where: { Sequelize.col('group.members.id'): userId }

Comment: I can also clearly see Sequelize sets `group.members.discord_id` in the query.

Comment: the problem comes from the prefix "Message." added. Could you try with the version before your edit ?

Comment: I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table "group.members"` then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177951/discussion-between-philippeauriach-and-freeline).